# How can I use the Perl debugger on the command line if I have a RemotePort configured in my .bashrc?

Tags: perl, bash

I've got my Bash set up to connect `perl -d` to my Windows box automatically so I can use the [Komodo IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_IDE) debugger. Unfortunately, my computer moved into a network that the box with the command line cannot connect to right now (vice versa works obviously).

This is the setting I use in `~/.bashrec`:

```
export PERLDB_OPTS="RemotePort=192.168.0.1:9000 async=1"
```

**How can I tell Perl on the command line to disregard these settings for the current command?**

```
$ perl -d foo.pl
Unable to connect to remote host: 192.168.0.1:9000 (Die Wartezeit für die Verbindung ist abgelaufen)
Running program outside the debugger...
```

Comment: `unset PERLDB_OPTS`. If you want to just unset them for one command, try `PERLDB_OPTS= perl-d foo.pl`; note the blank between `=` and `perl`.

Comment: Yay, does the trick. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unset PERLDB_OPTS`. If you want to just unset them for one command, try `PERLDB_OPTS= perl -d foo.pl`; note the blank between `=` and `perl`.

Comment: What about `PERL5DB`? Should it [be set to `BEGIN { require 'perl5db.pl'; }`](http://docs.komodoide.com/Manual/debugperl#To_disable_the_PDK_debugger:)?